# "Parameter not valid" error when trying to save the image converted from byte

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, image

currently I am testing a script that tries to save an image file converted from a string of HEX, however, when I try to execute the Save command, parameter not valid appears.

```
        // Some junk hex image data
        string hexImgData = @"FFD8FFE000104A46494600010200006400640000FFFFD9";

        // Call function to Convert the hex data to byte array
        byte[] newByte = ToByteArray(hexImgData);
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(newByte);

        // Save the memorystream to file
        Bitmap.FromStream(memStream).Save("C:\\img.jpg");


    // Function converts hex data into byte array
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(String HexString)
    {
        int NumberChars = HexString.Length;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        {
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(HexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

Currently I am still in the process of looking what causes this, please advice.

Comment: Are you sure `hexImgData` has valid `BitMap` content?
I mean the [Syntax and structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was  mentioned in the comments, your bitmap format is wrong, all you have is some random hex data and the `Bitmap.FromStream` method has no idea what to do with it. If you look at this [link](http://turrier.fr/tutoriels/form_02/create-a-bitmap-file-with-an-hexadecimal-editor.html) which discusses how to create a bitmap file with a hex editor it discusses the `BitmapHeader`, `BitmapInfoHeader`, and the `Pixel RGB Data`. I was able to create a bitmap using your code by taking the data from their example and using it.

```
string bitmapHeader = "424D860000000000000036000000";
string bitmapInfoHeader = "280000000500000005000000010018000000000050000000C40E0000C40E00000000000000000000";
string pixelData = "0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF000000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF000000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF000000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF000000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF0000FF00";


string hexImgData =  bitmapHeader + bitmapInfoHeader + pixelData;

// Call function to Convert the hex data to byte array
byte[] newByte = ToByteArray(hexImgData);
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(newByte);

pictureBox1.Image  = Bitmap.FromStream(memStream);
```

Comment: Hmm...it seems that the problem lies with my bitmap format...I tested with some hex strings from different image and it works....thx!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need convert incoming string from Base64 to byte array like this:

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
```